# How to change grand total only for one table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i really have no idea right now on how to only calculate first table grand total using one script of jquery/javascript

based code from : https://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1189/jquery-table-calculate-sum-all-rows

here the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Performing Calculations in a Table</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
      var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

      $tblrows.each(function(index) {
        var $tblrow = $(this);

        $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function() {

          var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
          var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
          var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

          if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

            $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
            var grandTotal = 0;

            $(".subtot").each(function() {
              var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
              grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });

            $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="tblProducts">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Sub-Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name="" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table><br><br>
  <table id="tblProducts2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Sub-Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name="" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

When i change the value in table tblProducts it calculate grand total of two table, how to separate the grand total for each table.
Sorry to ask, i really have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only select the `.subtot` input inside the current table you're in before updating it. Try this.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);

  $('table').each(function(){

    var $tbl = $(this);    
    var $tblrows = $tbl.find('tbody tr');

    $tblrows.each(function (index) {
      var $tblrow = $(this);

      $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function () {

        var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
        var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
        var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

        if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

          $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
          var grandTotal = 0;

          $tbl.find(".subtot").each(function () {
            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
          });

          $tbl.find('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Performing Calculations in a Table</title>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>

<table id="tblProducts">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Sub-Total</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name=""/></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table><br><br>
 <table id="tblProducts2">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Sub-Total</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name=""/></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery selectors just add your table id, and if you have multiple tables you can wrap the code in a function

```js
function addTotal(tableID) {
      $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
      var $tblrows = $(tableID + " tbody tr");

      $tblrows.each(function(index) {
        var $tblrow = $(this);

        $tblrow.find( '.qty').on('change', function() {

          var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
          var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
          var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

          if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

            $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
            var grandTotal = 0;

            $(tableID + " .subtot").each(function() {
              var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
              grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });

            $(tableID + ' .grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
          }
        });
    });
}

addTotal("#tblProducts");
```

Answer (score -1):

You really don't need to loop over the rows to add the event listener.

You can use `closest()` within the handler function to isolate the row and table the element is in then use `find()`

```js
$('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot').prop('readonly', true);
$('.qty').on('change', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    qty = $(this).val(),
    price = $row.find(".price").val(),
    subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

  if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

    $row.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
    var grandTotal = 0;
    var $table = $row.closest('table')

    $table.find(".subtot").each(function() {
      var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
      grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
    });

    $table.find('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblProducts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Sub-Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table><br><br>
<table id="tblProducts2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Sub-Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product One" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="220" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Two" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="18.32" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Three" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="29" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="pnm" value="Product Four" name="pnm" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="" name="qty" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" value="19.99" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtot" value="0" name="subtot" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="grdtot" value="" name="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```